# TitleCase Exercise using JAVA

Tags: java

I just need clarification on this one.
I'm doing a certain exercise on java--

*Write a static method that will replace all the first letter
of every word in a String with capital letters.
Example: a string is just a string ----> A String Is Just A String*

I was able to accomplish the desired output but I got confused on this part of my code.

THIS SEEMS TO WORK:

```
char j;
if (length > 1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        j = str2.charAt(i);
        if (j == ' ') {
            str = str + j + (Character.toUpperCase(str2.charAt(i + 1)));
            i++; //    for skip
        } else {
            str = str + j;
        }
    } 
} else {
    str = "Please enter a string.";
}
```

HOWEVER, WHEN I PUT IT THIS WAY IT DOESN’T SEEM TO WORK:

```
Char j, k; 
if (length > 1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        j = str2.charAt(i);
        k = str2.charAt(i + 1);
        if (j == ' ') {
            str = str + j + (Character.toUpperCase(k));
            i++; //    for skip
        } else {
            str = str + j;
        }
    }
} else {
    str = "Please enter a string.";
}
```

Can someone please explain why? Did I miss or overlook something?

Here's the whole code by the way:

```
package exercises.exercisesday3.part1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise5CapitalLetters {
public static void main(String args[]) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter source String: ");
String capital = myTitleCase(" " + input.nextLine());

System.out.println(capital);

input.close();
}

public static String myTitleCase(String capitalLetter) {

String str = "";
String str2 = capitalLetter.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");

int length = str2.length();

char j;
if (length > 1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        j = str2.charAt(i);
        if (j == ' ') {
        str = str + j + (Character.toUpperCase(str2.charAt(i + 1)));
        i++; //    for skip
        } else {
        str = str + j;
        }
    }
} else {
    str = "Please enter a string.";
    }
    return str.trim();
    }
}
```

Comment: You may need to provide more details about your question specially  initialization of variables such as length, str2, str etc. Otherwise users will get difficult to provide solid answer

Comment: Noted. Will provide the whole code.

Comment: @Coder done editing question. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is due to the incorrect way of reading the value for k as `k = str2.charAt(i + 1)` it should be changed as show in below code.

In your code try to access the character beyond the length of the String provided.

This should be the corrected code

```
    char j, k=0; 
    if (length > 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            j = str2.charAt(i);
            if(i!=length-1){
                k = str2.charAt(i + 1);
            }               
            if (j == ' ') {
                str = str + j + (Character.toUpperCase(k));
                i++; //    for skip
            } else {
                str = str + j;
            }
        }
    } else {
        str = "Please enter a string.";
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code and got this result
Enter source String: 
a string is just a string
A String Is Just A Strin

Comment: the character "g" is missing.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! @Coder